# How can I add a error bar in dataframe and in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making a grouped bar graph using ggplot2. However, I am having trouble adding sd/sem. The standard errors are: '1,2,3,1'. How can I add Error Bar to this bar graph?

```
survey <- data.frame(group=rep(c("LG", "RM"),each=2),
                sample=rep(c("sample1", "sample2"),1),
                values=c(200,50,300,25 ))


library(ggplot2)
ggplot(survey, aes(x=sample, y=values, fill=group)) + 
 geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())
```

Comment: There is only observation for each group/sample

Comment: This sample data is from online literature. I do not have access to raw data. I can only access mean and se. Hence, I want to enter standard manually with only one observation. But in reality this data is not just one observation.

Comment: In that case, can you try `ggplot(survey, aes(x=sample, y=values, fill=group)) +
  stat_summary(geom = "bar", fun.y = mean, position = "dodge") +
  stat_summary(geom = "errorbar", fun.data = mean_se, position = "dodge")`

Comment: Thank you. I will modify this

Comment: Can you check if it works for your big dataset

Comment: I tried. But I am not seeing an error bar. Please check it if there is anything wrong here                                                                                                  survey <- data.frame(group=rep(c("LG", "RM"),each=2),
                     sample=rep(c("sample1", "sample2"),1),
                     values=c(200,50,300,25),
                     mean_se=c(10,2,20,5))
survey

ggplot(survey, aes(x=sample, y=values, fill=group)) +
  stat_summary(geom = "bar", fun.y = mean, position = "dodge") + 
  stat_summary(geom = "errorbar", fun.data = mean_se, position = "dodge")

Comment: as i said it works when the no of obs is greater than 1

Comment: ok, thank you, I understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case just put the fixed values directly, as they were calculated already somewhere else.

```r
survey <- data.frame(group=rep(c("LG", "RM"),each=2),
                     sample=rep(c("sample1", "sample2"),1),
                     values=c(200,50,300,25 ),
                     se=c(1,2,3,1)) #added values here


library(ggplot2)
ggplot(survey, aes(x=sample, y=values, fill=group)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=values - se, ymax=values + se),
                position=position_dodge(width = 0.9),width=0.5)
```

gives:

[image]

Comment: btw: in this case, `geom_col` instead of `geom_bar` might be better suited for your needs.